# How to validate whether the selected date has any consecutive in the dates array in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation

Let's say **01/01/2022** is selected from the input, and my dates array is something like below

```
['31/12/2021', '01/11/2021', '02/01/2022'...]
```

then my form validation must fire and gives a validation error since **'31/12/2021'** and **'02/01/2022'** are consecutive dates for the selected date.

I'm using the reactive forms technique here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Map for dates that are previous to every date in your array and another for the following dates and compare if both have the same input date.

```
const previous = {[key: string]: string}
previous = { '02/01/2022' : '01/01/2022'}

const following = {[key: string]: string}
following = { '31/12/2021' : '01/01/2022'}
```

and do something like

```
 if(previous['02/01/2022'] === following['31/12/2021']){
    //fire error here
```

}